# Convert Type object to Type of List<object>

Tags: c#, reflection, types

Considering I have the following:

```
Type objectType = typeof(A);
```

How can I convert objectType to collectionType?
Knowing that collectionType represents the following:

```
Type collectionType = typeof(IList<A>);
```

Comment: What do you mean by convert to collectionType?

Comment: `typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(A))`

Comment: I have a method that returns me Type of a certain object. But I need to get the type of a collection of that same object to use it in AutoMapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @PetSerAl mentioned in the comments, the way to do it is like this:

```
typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(A))
```